# Circular links on the site

Tags: javascript, html

I want the code in the  tags to make the links that refer to themselves removed in the  tag. Tell me what is wrong?

```
        ...
        <div class="bs-docs-sidebar__scroll-container">
            {# Для подключения програмного скрола необходимо добавить класс mCustomScrollbar #}
            <ul class="nav bs-docs-sidenav bs-docs-sidenav_with-scroll" data-spy="affix" data-offset-bottom="153">
                <h5 class="sb">
                    <a href="/catalog/{{folder_0.uri}}/">
                        {{folder_0.name}}
                    </a>
                </h5>
                <script>
                    $('.sb').children('a').each(function() {
                         var link = $(this).attr('href');
                         var link2 = document.location.href;
                      if (link == link2) {
                        $(this).replaceWith(function(index, oldHTML){
                          return $("<span>").html(oldHTML);
                          });
                      }
                    });
            </script>

                {% for f in folder_items %}
                    {% if not f.hidden == 1 %}
                        {% if f.uri ==  folder_1.uri %}
                            <li class="active">
                                <a{% sytranslate_markup 'tree' 'name' f.id %} title="{{f.name}}">
                                    <span>{{f.name}}</span>
                                </a>
                                <span class="count">{{f.product_count}}</span>
                            </li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li>
                                <a{% sytranslate_markup 'tree' 'name' f.id %} href="/catalog/{{folder_0.uri}}/{{f.uri}}/"
                                    class="js-show-veil------"
                                    title="{{f.name}}">
                                    <span>{{f.name}}</span>
                                </a>
                                <span class="count">{{f.product_count}}</span>
                            </li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>

        </div>
        .....
```

I’m trying to do what I want with this script, I can’t understand what’s wrong? I tried to embed the code in different ways and after different tags.

Please, help!

Comment: Yes, what's wrong? Please describe your problem, what you want your code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: @Teemu 
I want the code in the <script> tags to make the links that refer to themselves removed in the <nav> tag.

Comment: Yes, but what are you getting? An error message? The code runs, no errors, but links are not removed? Nothing happens at all? The code steals your neighbour's bike? I guess the second, take a look at the jQuery selector you're trying to run `each` loop, it doesn't select anything.

Comment: @Teemu that's why I turned here to ask why it doesn’t choose anything. Nothing happens, no error messages. I don’t understand why nothing is selected, because I indicated the class where to choose from ...

Comment: You've to take a look at how [jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) work. Currently you're targeting `affix-top` __tag__ which is a child of `hidden-print` __tag__ which is a child of `bs-docs-sidebar_with-scroll` __tag__ which is a child in an element having `bs-docs-sidebar` class.

Comment: @Teemu I added the answer to the question

Comment: What you specifically need, is [this](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).